# NodeJS two queries in one route

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to display `Invitation` and `Comments` in the same rendered file (show.hbs)

I have this code here, and it's working fine, except I cannot achieve that comment's would also display. I would really appreciate any help.

I'm not getting any errors with this code.

```
app.get('/invitation/:id', (req, res) => {

  let id = req.params.id;

  if(!ObjectID.isValid(id)){
    return res.status(404).send();
  }

  Comment.find({inviteId: id}).then((comment) => {
    if(!comment){
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
    res.render('show.hbs', {comment});
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(404).send();
  });

  Invitation.findById(id).then((invitation) => {
      if(!invitation){
        return res.status(404).send();
      }
    res.render('show.hbs', {invitation});
}, (e) => {
  res.status(404).send();
});

}, (e) => {
  console.log('Unable to find invitation', e);
});
```

Comment: Nest the `find` functions inside each other?

Comment: @madebydavid I'm thinking the same, but don't have experience how to nest functons in js. Will google that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
Invitation.findById(id).then((invitation) => {
if (!invitation) {
    return res.status(404).send();
}
Comment.find({ inviteId: id }).then((comment) => {
    if (!comment) {
        return res.status(404).send();
    }
    res.render('show.hbs', { comment, invitation});
}, (e) => {
    res.status(404).send();
});    
}, (e) => {
res.status(404).send();
});
```

and render it with both invitation and comment

Answer (score 1):

Tnx to @vibhor1997a but this is much prettier

```
try {
  let invitation = await Invitation.findById(id).then((invitation) => {
  if (!invitation) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  let comments = await Comment.find({ inviteId: id })
  if (!comments) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  return res.render('show.hbs', { comments, invitation});
} catch (e) {
  return res.status(500).send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste your error message, but I'm pretty sure it's something like `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client`.

Just nest your queries or use `await` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await.